# FPDF. Adding page portrait works for first page only

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm attempting to use FPDF in portrait mode, but because my data takes up more than 1 page, the pages afterward are generated in landscape mode. Is there a way to make the dynamically-generated pages the same format? My code usage is as follows:

```
$w = array(60, 70, 55);

$title = 'Example TItle';

$pdf = new PDFnew();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',8);

$pdf->AddPage('P');

$pdf->PrintTable($header,$data,$w, $title);

$pdf->Output('F', '/path/to/example.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of FPDF you are using as the current API has no method called `PDFnew`. However, the current API's constructor takes an orientation parameter to set the default orientation. If you're using FPDF v1.82 you can replace:

```php
$pdf = new PDFnew();
```

with

```php
$pdf = new FPDF('P');
```

and the default orientation will be portrait.

Comment: Changing versions (and thus class names used for instantiation), doesn't help.

Comment: What version are you using?